# Flags in Kim Possible (2019)

Tags: props, kim-possible-2019

In a scene near the end of the TV movie *Kim Possible* (2019), two flags are seen on two different flag poles outside of the Middleton high school.  I don't remember, but they might also be seen in earlier shots of the outside of the school.

The flag on the left in that scene is divided vertically,  purple toward the staff and blue on the other end, &has a large "M" on it possibly for Middleton, and the other flag has a lot of purple and gold.

I guess that the flags could represent any two out of the following:

1. Middleton High School.
2. Middleton School District.
3. Middleton town or city.
4. The county Middleton is in.
5. The state or province Middleton is in.  Except that no US state or Canadian province have any purple in its flag.
6. The country Middleton is in.  Except that Middleton is supposed to be in the USA and the American flag was not seen.

Or maybe the flags stand for something else.

So does anyone know what the flags represent or have good pictures of their design?

Comment: Images here would be ideal but why is this **important** to the further understanding of the plot of the movie. This seems to be *trivia* at best.